# jQuery get all text in div

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my code

```
<div class="formItem">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Test Label:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">Test Text</asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

If I use jQuery

```
alert($('.formItem').text())
```

the result will be "Test Label:"

How can I get the result as "Test Label:Test Text"

Comment: It would help if you posted the generated HTML instead of ASP code.

Answer (score 2):

use the following,

```
alert($('.formItem').text() + ":" + $('.formItem #TextBox1').val()');
```

Comment: ``val`` is a function, not a property.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation

I can see what you were thinking.

```
alert($('.formItem').text())
```

This does in fact print out all the text inside the class `.formItem`. The problem, however, is that the input (textbox) doesn't have text, it only has a value.
Or, to be more accurate, it has an attribute called `value`. It is not as apparent in your ASP example.

Normally, the html would look something like this

```
<div class="formItem">
    <label id="Label1" for="TextBox1">Test Label:</label>
    <input id="TextBox1" type='text' value='Test Text' />
</div>
```

In JQuery, to retrieve the `value` attribute, there is a shorthand function called [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), and is the equivalent of [`.attr("value")`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

---

## Solution

[Here's a JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/DW7mZ/1/)

A simple approach, would be to treat the elements separately and then concatenate the strings.

```
alert( $("#Label1").text() + " " + $("#TextBox1").val() );
```

This would output `"Test Label: Test Text"`

---

## Alternative solution

[Here's a JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/DW7mZ/2/)

To demonstrate how you could do this with a parent container, I will use the functions [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) and [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var sResult = "";
$('.formItem').children().each(function(){
    var sOutput = $(this).text();

    //check if the text is empty for the child, then get the value instead
    if(sOutput == "") 
        sOutput = $(this).val();

    //if the text isn't empty, add it to the result string
    if(sOutput != "")
        sResult += " "+sOutput;
});

alert(sResult);
```

This would also output `"Test Label: Test Text"`

Note that this example doesn't need to know the names of the label and input elements, this also affects all `.formItem` containers.

[Check this example out.](http://jsfiddle.net/DW7mZ/3/)

Comment: I would use the Alternative solution from ShadowScripter, because my Label & Textbox will increased from time to time.

Comment: Hi ShadowScripter, your code is pretty good for me. But I had another problem when use the code when a dropdownlist inside the div. I get all the Items in dropdown list but not only the selected item. Can you please advise me how to improve the code?

Comment: @user1125107 I can't really help you until I see your current code. I advise you to create a new question so someone can help you. Give me the link to the new question and I can take a look at it. Also, please mark the best answer to your question as "Accepted" (little green check-sign).

Answer (score 0):

The asp:TextBox is an input, which you can retrieve via the element's val() method.

Something like this:

```
alert($('.formItem').text() + $('.formItem').find("input[text]").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does show the whole text:

http://jsfiddle.net/N3bM9/1/

Note I switched out the ASP tags for divs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.formItem label').text() + $('#TextBox1').val();
```